# How do you determine the current video FPS in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, frame-rate, getusermedia

When playing a VideoTrack in WebRTC how do you determine the current framerate/FPS? Do you need to calculate this yourself or is there a method I can call to retrieve this value?